# What happened on "2017-9-21 23:59"?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I used a calander and add one minute to it each time. but in date "2017-9-21  23:59" something strange happent. The date come one hour back. It's behavior is like date saving time, but that time date saving must not happent.

here is my code and output:

```
GregorianCalendar fromCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(2017, 8, 21, 22, 58);

    for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
        System.out.println(fromCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-"
                + (fromCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" +   fromCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " "
                + fromCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + fromCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "      ");
        fromCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    }
```

Output:

```
.
.
.
2017-9-21 23:58     
2017-9-21 23:59     
2017-9-21 23:0      
2017-9-21 23:1      
2017-9-21 23:2  
.
.
.
```

Is there any simple point I misunderstood about it?

Comment: Why do you think no DST change must happen then?

Comment: What is your timezone? Your code works fine for me in UTC-07:00

Comment: I cannot more strongly advise against using the legacy `java.util.Calendar`.  You should instead look at the `java.time` package and select the class appropriate for your use case.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `GregorianCalendar`, [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: You should not have @JimGarrison tell you which time zone your date-time object is using. Instead you should tell it which time zone it should use. If you want to avoid any and all DST transitions, one solution is to use UTC, for example `OffsetDateTime.of(2017, 8, 21, 22, 58, 0, 0, ZoneOffet.UTC).plusMinutes(1).plusMinutes(1)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the TimeAndDate.com DST page](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2017.html) there is only ONE country in the world where the DST changeover happened at 00:00 on 2017/09/22: Iran

Therefore you must be using [the timezone for Iran: `Asia/Tehran`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_Standard_Time).

Comment: Good sleuthing :)

Comment: Can be verified by adding `fromCalendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));` just after `GregorianCalendar fromCalendar = ...`

Comment: Nitpicking, locale and time zone are two different things. The OP must be using the *time zone* for Iran.

Answer (score 3):

The [Answer by Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48162681/642706) is correct and should be accepted. You are apparently seeing a [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) cut-over for a time zone such as [`Asia/Tehran`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tehran).

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Specify a time zone using [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tehran" ) ;  // Testing the Daylight Saving Time cut-over in Iran.
ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ZonedDateTime.of( 2017 , 9 , 21 , 23 , 59 , 0 , 0 , z );  // Set the moment to what might *appear* be the minute before midnight but is not, is actually an hour and a minute before midnight. 
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = zdt1.plusMinutes( 1 );  // Adding a minute takes us to 11 PM again, but with a different offset-from-UTC, for a 25-hours long day.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "zdt1: " + zdt1 );
System.out.println( "zdt2: " + zdt2 );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne](https://ideone.com/wTwxyE).com.

> zdt1: 2017-09-21T23:59+04:30[Asia/Tehran]
>
> zdt2: 2017-09-21T23:00+03:30[Asia/Tehran]

Notice how adding a minute to roll-over midnight sent us back to 11 PM on the same date but with a different [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), `03:30` versus `04:30`. So the 21st of September 2017 in Iran ran 25 hours long.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).